# When listed nameservers for domain does not report the same set of nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I was using DNSCheck and all my nameservers are correct.
But I noticed a warning for my domain:

> The listed nameservers for gabrielfair.com does not all report the same set of nameservers

[image: Consistency Check from DNSCheck.ripe.com]

Since the serial numbers are consistent I am confused by this warning.

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like the software that is validating your setup is testing to ensure all 3 name servers you have set return the same records... and they don't.

It looks like this is on purpose also to do with balancing the DNS load.
when doing the following tests:

`dig @NS1.DREAMHOST.COM ns gabrielfair.com`

I get an answer like:

`;; ANSWER SECTION:
gabrielfair.com.    14400   IN  NS  ns3.dreamhost.com.
gabrielfair.com.    14400   IN  NS  ns2.dreamhost.com.
gabrielfair.com.    14400   IN  NS  ns1.dreamhost.com.`

Testing NS2:

`dig @NS2.DREAMHOST.COM ns gabrielfair.com`

I get an answer like:

`;; ANSWER SECTION:
gabrielfair.com.    14400   IN  NS  ns2.dreamhost.com.
gabrielfair.com.    14400   IN  NS  ns1.dreamhost.com.
gabrielfair.com.    14400   IN  NS  ns3.dreamhost.com.`

And testing NS3:

`dig @NS3.DREAMHOST.COM ns gabrielfair.com``

I get an answer like:

`;; ANSWER SECTION:
gabrielfair.com.    14400   IN  NS  ns2.dreamhost.com.
gabrielfair.com.    14400   IN  NS  ns1.dreamhost.com.
gabrielfair.com.    14400   IN  NS  ns3.dreamhost.com.`

Although the hosts are the same the order is different when NS1 is queried.

I dont think this is something to worry about unless the validator will not let you skip it.

Comment: Ordering is not relevant when returning NS records. If you run a similar test for another domain you will get different orderings each time you query, even for the same nameserver: `dig @ns1.google.com google.com NS`. Could it be a tool glitch, or a timing issue, for example if when the test was run the NS records were inconsistent but now they aren't.

Comment: @AndréFernandes I agree that the ordering should not be relevant yet there is the error and the only difference i see consistently is the ordering. Do you have insight with regards to what validation software is and how it works?

Comment: @cormpadre I haven't looked into what it does specifically, but I believe this is the validation software in question: https://github.com/dotse/dnscheck  I don't see why it would care about the ordering, if it does that would appear to be a clear bug (and fairly visible one at that).

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist how is your pearl? seems to be in this file https://github.com/dotse/dnscheck/blob/master/engine/lib/DNSCheck/Test/Consistency.pm  the check is on line 142 to 162.. but i dont fully understand it..but cannot see anything obvious that would change the order of the set. To me it looks like it just stores a list as provided and compares them.

Comment: @cormpadre Looks ok to me after a cursory look; it makes the values all uppercase and sorts them before use (147).

Comment: You should use `zonemaster`, it is the successor of `dnscheck`.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist thanks for the look, ok then strange tho.